# Monitoring CPU Core Usage on Terminal Servers

Tags: monitoring, terminal-services

I have windows 2003 terminal servers, multi-core.  I'm looking for a way to monitor individual CPU core usage on these servers.  It is possible for an end-user to have a run-away process (e.g.  Internet Explorer or Outlook).  The core for that process may spike to near 100% leaving the other cores 'normal'.  Thus, the overall CPU usage on the server is just the total of all the cores or if 7 of the cores on a 8 core server are idle and the 8th is running at 100% then 1/8 = 12.5% usage.

What utility can I use to monitor multiple servers ?  If the CPU usage for a core is "high" what would I use to determine the offending process and then how could I automatically kill that process if it was on the 'approved kill process' list?

A product from http://www.packettrap.com/ called PT360 would be perfect except they use SMNP to get data and SMNP appears to only give total CPU usage, it's not broken out by an individual core.   Take a look at their Dashboard option with the CPU gauge 'gadget'.  That's exactly what I need if only it worked at the core level.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Individual CPU usage is available through the standard windows performance counters.  You can monitor this in perfmon.

However, it won't give you the result you are looking for.  Unless a thread/process has been explicitly bound to a single CPU then a run-away process will not spike one core to 100% while all the others idle.  The run-away process will bounce around between all the processors.  I don't know why windows schedules threads this way, presumably because there is no gain from forcing affinity and some loss due to having to handle interrupts on particular cores.

You can see this easily enough just in task manager.  Watch the individual CPU graphs when you have a single compute bound process running.

Answer (score 1):

You can give [Spotlight on Windows](http://www.quest.com/spotlight-on-windows/) a try. You can graphically drill into all sorts of performance and load indicators. Its freeware.

Answer (score 0):

perfmon from Microsoft can monitor each individual CPU. perfmon also works remote and you can monitor farious aspects of Windows.

I'm not sure if it helps to find run-away processes because the Windows scheduler dos not execute a process always on the same CPU -> on your 8 CPU machine you will see 12.5 % usage on all CPU's if one process runs away.